# Windows Task Scheduler broken: "service is not available"

Tags: windows-vista, task-scheduler

### Problem

I'm trying to run Windows Task Scheduler from the start menu (the command is `%SystemRoot%\system32\taskschd.msc /s`) but as of very recently, I'm getting an error:

[image: Task Scheduler service is not available. Verify that the service is running.]

The window then opens as usual except no tasks are displayed and the error "Reading Data Failed" is shown on a few of the panels.

[image: second screenshot]

### Possible Causes

- ran rpccfg -a 1 and netsh rpc add 127.0.0.1
- changed PC name twice while computer was still loading
- installed and used DeltaCopy
- installed Adobe AIR
- installed Warsow

I can't think of any other system changes I've made.

### Things Tried

- ran rpccfg with the parameter to reset to defaults
- ran netsh with the parameter to reset to defaults
- uninstalled DeltaCopy
- forced the service to restart. The service and its dependencies appear started and looked normal before and after
- connecting to "another computer" from inside the program and entering credentials for the current machine. This said access denied yesterday but today it says "Connecting as another user is only supported when connecting to a computer running Windows Vista™ or later." and partially works but doesn't show my tasks.

[image: third screenshot]

but I *am* on Vista!

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that having some specific network as a task condition caused this problem. Changing the value to **Any connection** solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a System Restore using a restore point dated far back enough 
when you think the task Scheduler service was there.

Go to
START> 
type rstrui - select a restore point

If you try System Restore,but it says you have no restore points!
That does not work for you you might try a repair install.

Run a Windows System Restore from the Original Windows Vista DVD.

HERE is a tutorial to do this:
[REPAIR INSTALL VISTA](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/88236-repair-install-vista.html)
IF you do not have the CD/DVD RESTORE of your VISTA try to download this one:
[ALL VISTA RECOVERY CD/DVD](http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/)

Hope this can help you fix the problem.
Den.

Comment: 1. No restore points. 2. Vista DVD was not provided with my computer.